# Scrolling is not working on mobile device specially in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone I am having issues in this http://subhaweddings.com website, while scrolling in chrome browser using one finger touch it doesn't work not only in mobile in the computer also but using a mouse it work fine in computer and with two finger scrolling also good in mobile, what could be the issue?
http://subhaweddings.com

Answer (score 0):

If you remove:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

from body, then it will work.

[image]

Comment: from exactly where i suppose to remove this from which file?

Comment: I edited my answer, see screenshot for additional explanation. Probably some javascript plugin adds this to your body tag.